# Entity Framework 4.0 Dependencies

Tags: .net, entity-framework

From what limited info we have about EF 4.0, does anyone know if we would be able to use EF 4.0 in our IIS 6.0 (Windows Server 2003) using .NET 3.5?

I imagine  EF 4.0 to siginify .NET 4.0 framework.  It'll probably take a year for us to upgrade our production servers to .NET 4.0 some I'm wondering is if we play the waiting game or not for some of our development decisions...

Also, anyone have any idea of when Ef 4.0 could potentially be released?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EF 4.0 will be a part of .NET 4.0

So no you won't be able to use it in a .NET 3.5 website.

In terms of when it get released you can expect it at the same time VS 2010 and .NET 4.0 are released.

Hope this helps

Alex

Program Manager - Entity Framework Team - Microsoft.